# Problem with OAuth, Twitter and Android: fails in http-communication with the server

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter4j, signpost

Does anyone have a working example of OAuth authentication for twitter with Android? I have tried to use both Twitter4J and SignPost, but I get very strange errors, saying twitter.com is an unknown host. I have understod that there is a problem ([under Google Android](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/)) with the SignPost library and Android and according to the project's home-page, the CommonsHttpOAuth* classes shall work.

Here is my SignPost:

```
private void getReqTokenAndAuthenticateUsingSignPost() {
    String callbackUrl = "twitter-test:///";
    CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY,
            CONSUMER_SECRET);
    CommonsHttpOAuthProvider provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(
            "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
            "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

    String tokenStr = consumer.getToken();
    String tokenSecretStr = consumer.getTokenSecret();

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor edit = preferences.edit();
    edit.putString(REQ_TOKEN, tokenStr);
    edit.putString(REQ_TOKEN_SECRET, tokenSecretStr);

    try {
        String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, callbackUrl);
        Uri authenticationUri = Uri.parse(authUrl);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, authenticationUri));
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and here is my code for Twitter4J:

```
private void getReqTokenAndAuthenticateUsingTwitter4J() {

    String callbackUrl = "twitter-test:///";
    try {
        // Prepare a request token, based on consumer key and consumer
        // secret
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration cfg = builder.build();
        Twitter t = new TwitterFactory(cfg).getInstance();

        RequestToken requestToken = t.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackUrl);
        String tokenStr = requestToken.getToken();
        String tokenSecretStr = requestToken.getTokenSecret();

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor edit = preferences.edit();
        edit.putString(REQ_TOKEN, tokenStr);
        edit.putString(REQ_TOKEN_SECRET, tokenSecretStr);
        if (edit.commit()) {
            // Launch the browser for authentication in twitter's web-gui
            Uri authenticationUri = Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, authenticationUri));
        }
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and yes, I have a manifest with Internet permission and an intent filter for the callback-url. Here is the output from logcat when running the SignPost code:

```
W/System.err(  779): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: twitter.com
W/System.err(  779):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
W/System.err(  779):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
W/System.err(  779):    at com.examples.twitterimages.TwitterImagesActivity.getReqTokenAndAuthenticateUsingSignPost(TwitterImagesActivity.java:109)
W/System.err(  779):    at com.examples.twitterimages.TwitterImagesActivity.onCreate(TwitterImagesActivity.java:64)
W/System.err(  779):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
W/System.err(  779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
W/System.err(  779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
W/System.err(  779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
W/System.err(  779):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
W/System.err(  779):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err(  779):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err(  779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
W/System.err(  779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(  779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
W/System.err(  779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
W/System.err(  779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
W/System.err(  779):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err(  779): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: twitter.com
W/System.err(  779):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
W/System.err(  779):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
W/System.err(  779):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
W/System.err(  779):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
W/System.err(  779):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
W/System.err(  779):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
W/System.err(  779):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
W/System.err(  779):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
W/System.err(  779):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
W/System.err(  779):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
W/System.err(  779):    at oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider.sendRequest(CommonsHttpOAuthProvider.java:64)
W/System.err(  779):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:177)
W/System.err(  779):    ... 16 more
```

and here is the output when running the Twitter4J code:

```
W/System.err(  817): api.twitter.comRelevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
W/System.err(  817):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=6c607809 or
W/System.err(  817):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0f1d8134
W/System.err(  817): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[6c607809-0f1d8134 6c607809-0f1d810a], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.1}
W/System.err(  817):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:204)
W/System.err(  817):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
W/System.err(  817):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:102)
W/System.err(  817):    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:108)
W/System.err(  817):    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:271)
W/System.err(  817):    at com.examples.twitterimages.TwitterImagesActivity.getReqTokenAndAuthenticateUsingTwitter4J(TwitterImagesActivity.java:136)
W/System.err(  817):    at com.examples.twitterimages.TwitterImagesActivity.onCreate(TwitterImagesActivity.java:64)
W/System.err(  817):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
W/System.err(  817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
W/System.err(  817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
W/System.err(  817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
W/System.err(  817):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
W/System.err(  817):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err(  817):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err(  817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
W/System.err(  817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(  817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
W/System.err(  817):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
W/System.err(  817):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
W/System.err(  817):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err(  817): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.twitter.com
W/System.err(  817):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
W/System.err(  817):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
W/System.err(  817):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
W/System.err(  817):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
W/System.err(  817):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
W/System.err(  817):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
W/System.err(  817):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
W/System.err(  817):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
W/System.err(  817):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
W/System.err(  817):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
W/System.err(  817):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:614)
W/System.err(  817):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:162)
W/System.err(  817):    ... 19 more
```

Have anybody resolved this? I'm stuck here. I can get the code to run as a Java SE program, but it fails on android...

// Jonas

Comment: Have you solved this problem??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check and Confirm Two Things -

1-**Give Callback URL in Your twitter app created by you on twitter website (Go to your app-> settings->callback url)** [Click here](https://dev.twitter.com/)

2-**Go to Phone settings then click 'Date and Time' and select 'Automatic' (Please make sure your device Time Zone and Time,Date all are correct)**  If your time,Date and Time Zone are not correct then you can not tweet.

Comment: hi it's working in emulator did not work in my device do u know the solution  for this problem

Comment: @Pandiyan  Please correct emulators time,date and time zone And make sure You can access twitter on your network.For this Please login to twitter website on your computer that is  connecting with the same network as your emulator

Comment: @Atul Bhardwaj sir my emulator date & time is correct and it's working my emulator but not working in my device that is my probm

Comment: set date and time twitter login

Answer (score 3):

I have a tutorial to setup OAuth for [Twitter with Twitter4J on Android here](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html), it includes the complete project source code to download as well - so that might help.

As for your specific issue - are you able to connect to the internet via the android emulator? it looks as though it is failing to connect - do you have any other apps on the emulator that attempt to connect the internet that you could try and test against? sometimes when I run the emulator if the internet connection fails then the signal bar on the emulator appears with an X by it and no-bars.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I copied my manifest from another project and mal-placed my permission tags. Doh.

Comment: @rhinds does your twitter oauth turoial work in versions 3.2 and up? Im experiencing problems getting my code to run in version 4.0 as android has added a new exception that doesn't allow any network tasks to be run on the ui thread anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I've used SignPost in Android exactly for twitter client, works fine.

1. Have you tried opening a browser in android and going to twitter.com?
2. Try to connect to any url from the code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I solved it (I wrote that above). I had messed up my manifest and spelled the internet permission bad. T

Answer (score 0):

for me i was using http:  instead of https: for the request URI's