# Communication with the service provider failed : Twitter

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am getting Communication with the service provider failed: Received authentication challenge is null

Comment: Go to settings(in your phone) then click 'Date & Time' and select 'Automatic'  This solved my Problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Give Callback URL in your Twitter app created by you on the Twitter website.
2. Go to Phone settings then click 'Date and Time' and select 'Automatic'.And Please check your Date,Time and TimeZone are correct

Comment: /**For more details check this link**/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324474/problem-with-oauth-twitter-and-android-fails-in-http-communication-with-the-se/9987465#9987465

Answer (score 1):

for me i was using  DefaultOAuthProvider as my oAuth provider instead of CommonsHttpOAuthProvider   ... also make sure when your retrieving the access token its off of the main thread.