# How to upload Image to twitter using update_with_media twitter api in android?

Tags: android

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json
```

After doing a lots of research on how to post image on twitter,I got this url to post image to twitter.But I didnt know how to use this and what parameters I need to pass.

I also found that

1) Posting to Twitpic is one of the way to post image to twitter,but I didnt know how to use that twitpic library.

```
I am familiar with posting image to facebook using graph api (url and accesstoken),so I feel that posting image using the above API is much easier.
```

please suggest me in using the above api

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

check below code: you have to use use `twitter4j-core-2.1.11.jar` & `twitpic4j.jar`

before use this [checkthispost](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/05/share-text-to-facebook-twitter-android.html).

Login in to twitter using above android code.

You must have to login in twitter and use `OAUTH_TOKEN` & `OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET` in this method. in this i have passed `URL` same way you can also pass `bitmap`.

```
private void hello() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url;

        long result = 0;

        String oth = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
        String src = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

        Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY)
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET)
                .setOAuthAccessToken(oth).setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(src)
                .build();

        OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(conf,
                conf.getOAuthConsumerKey(), conf.getOAuthConsumerSecret(),
                new AccessToken(conf.getOAuthAccessToken(),
                        conf.getOAuthAccessTokenSecret()));

        ImageUpload upload = ImageUpload.getTwitpicUploader(
                Constants.twitpic_api_key, auth);

        Log.d(main_genral_class.TAG, "Start sending image...");

        try {
                url = upload.upload(" ", new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz0qZ.jpg").openStream(),
                        "some text");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

`url` is give you URL of uploaded image

for bitmap you can use like : `upload.upload(String, inputstream);`

**`Edited`**

I have checked my code and replace `twitter4j-core-2.1.11.jar` to `twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar`

check full code [here](https://github.com/dhaval0122/Share_to_Facebook_twitter.git)

and also change some setting in Twitter App on https://dev.twitter.com

[image]

[image: enter code here]

its working fine....

Comment: My twitter4j 2.2.5 jar doesnt contains the classes which you have used in this class,I already tried this.

Comment: use twitter4j-core-2.1.11.jar & twitpic4j.jar to execute this code.

Comment: I also have this jar file twitter4j-core-2.1.11.jar,but its not working now.I am sure because I have used this jar file now.It worked before 2 weeks but its not working now.

Comment: check log proper it give you some exception. you have checked this in android device or in simulator??

Comment: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Service provider responded in error: 301 (Moved Permanently)

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9987465/1168654 & if you have android OS 4.0 or above them add this "int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if (SDK_INT>8){

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

}"

Comment: no,I am testing this in Motorolo 2.3 version,but still I am getting this error.If you see the error report there is some line called Server is moved permanently.

Comment: thank u,I am having twitter2.2.5 ,its working fine but it is not having some classes which are used for twitpic.Could you please find solution for this if possible  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25159/discussion-between-user1891910-and-dhaval-sodha-parmar)

Answer (score 1):

Have look at this tutorial it solved my whole proble 
[Twit image along text](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/)

Comment: patient of what type?